# Re-using Bigtable connection with AbstractCloudBigtableTableDoFn

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-bigtable

I have a `DoFn` that extends `AbstractCloudBigtableTableDoFn<>` in order to send frequent Buffered Mutation requests to Bigtable.

When I run the job in the Cloud, I see repeated log entries at this step of the Dataflow pipeline that look like this:

```
Opening connection for projectId XXX, instanceId XXX, on data host batch-bigtable.googleapis.com, table admin host bigtableadmin.googleapis.com...
```

and

```
Bigtable options: BigtableOptions{XXXXX (lots of option entries here}
```

The code within the `DoFn` looks something like this:

```
@ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c)
    {
        try
        {
            BufferedMutator mPutUnit = getConnection().getBufferedMutator(TableName.valueOf(TABLE_NAME));

            for (CONDITION)
            {
                // create lots of different rowsIDs
                Put p = new Put(newRowID).addColumn(COL_FAMILY, COL_NAME, COL_VALUE);
                mPutUnit.mutate(p);
            }
            mPutUnit.close();
        } catch (IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
        c.output(0);
    }
```

This `DoFn` gets called very frequently.

Should I worry that Dataflow tries to re-establish the connection to Bigtable with every call to this `DoFn`? I was under the impression that inheriting from this class should ensure that a single connection to Bigtable should be re-used across all calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Opening connection for projectId ..." should appear once per worker per AbstractCloudBigtableTableDoFn instance. Can you double check that connections are being opened per call as opposed to per worker?

- Limit the number of workers to a handful
- In stack driver, expand the "Opening connection for projectId" messages and check if jsonPayload.worker is duplicated across different log messages.

Also, can you detail what version of the client you are using and what version of beam?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I raised the alarm too early. I had lots of workers for this job, and there are quite a few different DoFns that inherit from AbstractCloudBigtableDoFn, so I saw a lot of log entries at first, when the job just started, and got concerned, but eventually they stopped, as the job continued. So looks like it's all good. I don't see any reference to jsonPayload.worker in the details of the log entries. I am using Beam 2.2.0 and bigtable-hbase-beam 1.0.0. Thanks for your help!

Comment: We changed the implementation to open up new HBase Connections, new BigtableSessions, but keep the same underlying gRPC ChannelPool.  This actually isn't a problem.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions...

Yes, you should be worried that Dataflow tries to reestablish a connection to Bigtable with each call to the `DoFn`. The expected behavior of `AbstractCloudBigtableDoFn` is that a `Connection` instance is maintained per worker.

No, inheriting from `AbstractCloudBigtableDoFn` does not ensure a single `Connection` instance is reused for each call to the `DoFn`. This is not possible because the `DoFn` is serialized across multiple physical machines based on the number of workers allocated for the Dataflow job.

First, ensure that there are no connection/authentication issues to Bigtable. Occasionally, Dataflow will need to reestablish a connection to Bigtable. However, doing so for each call to the `DoFn` is not expected.

Comment: We have a setting where the underlying Channel pool object, which is the most expensive part of an HBase connection, is shared across VMs.